# php array object property

Tags: php, arrays, object, properties

Let me explain my problem with my code. This works:

```
$multiarray = array(
    'multikey1' => '',
    'multikey2' => ''
);
$array = array(
    'key1' => '',
    'key2' => '',
    'key3' => '',
    'key4' => $multiarray 
);
print_r($array);
```

This does not work:

```
class Array {

    public static $multiarray = array(
        'multikey1' => '',
        'multikey2' => '',
        'multikey3' => ''
    );

    public $array = array(
        'key1' => '',
        'key2' => self::$multiarray
    );
}

$array = new Array;
```

This does not work unfortunately. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can't create a class with the name Array. It's reserved.

Comment: @bobthyasian, thanks, but in my real code I ofcourse don't name that class Array, it just serves as an example

Comment: For future reference, while a short example is always appreciated, try to pick one that doesn't include unrelated bugs...

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize member variables to anything that is not constant, and you're trying include another array as a member variable, which would require runtime execution.

Also note that the `Array` class name is invalid, as it conflicts with the reserved word `array` used to create an array.

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

The workaround is to set your variable in the constructor:

```
class Array2 {
    public static $multiarray = array(
        'multikey1' =>  '',
        'multikey2' =>  '',
        'multikey3' =>  ''
    );

    public $array;

    function __construct() {
        $this->array = array(
            'key1'  =>  '',
            'key2'  =>  self::$multiarray
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am trying to comprehend your answer but I don't understand it. Could you illustrate your point maybe?

Comment: @Orhan classes are considered to be blueprints, and their property definitions need to be independent of any runtime environment or variables. Use the constructor to initialise properties that you want to contain variables (as nickb shows in the answer).